# Javascript: selenium webdriver isDisplayed() not working

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a test with selenium using JavaScript.

At one point in my test, I iterate through an array of input elements and want to fill in a value for the inputs which are visible.

```
if (textInputs.length > 0) {
    console.log('handling text input');
    var i, textInputLen;
    for (i = 0, textInputLen = textInputs.length; i < textInputLen; i++) {
      (function (index) {
        if (textInputs[index].isDisplayed()) {
            textInputs[index].sendKeys("custom text box - " + textBoxes);
            textBoxes++;
        }      
      }(i))
    }
  }
```

I keep getting the following error `ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible` because it is trying to fill in an input which is not displayed on the DOM. Why is it not working? How can I get it working?

I have tried a few thing instead of `isDisplayed()`:

1. I executed JS to see if the element had visibility set to hidden or display to none. Issue here is that the element bing displayed, in this case, is due to a slew of things and I am looking for something more general. IN this case, isDisplayed() *would* be exactly what I want.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

The method `.isDisplayed()` returns a promise and not the displayed state. Use `then` to get the resolved result:

```
element.isDisplayed().then(function(state){
    console.log(state):
});
```

But a better way would be to filter the list of elements with `webdriver.promise.filter`:

```
var textInputs = driver.findElements(By.css("input[type=text]"));

webdriver.promise.filter(textInputs, function(element) {
    return element.isDisplayed();
}).then(function(element) {
    element.sendKeys("my text");
});
```